# What is the difference between the 'href' and 'to' property in the link tag?

Tags: reactjs

While learning React I [stumbled upon](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example) a property I haven't seen before: "to" on a Link tag.

```
<Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
```

Can't find the docs to this - I guess it's a React specific property because I couldn't find it in the [regular docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp).

There must be a difference compared to "href" otherwise it shouldn't exist ;)
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just [found this here](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html) that may help give direction to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) `<Link/>`, so it's a bit special. It ties in to the `<Router>` and `<Route>` components and is used to navigate around in a Single-Page App. A standard anchor tag (even if it has an `href` that matches one of your `<Route>` paths) doesn't interact with React Router, so will cause a full-page reload.

Comment: ahh, now I see the difference is the capital 'L' I guess :D thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's a react router prop for navigation. It can be an object or a string.

> to - A string representation of the location to link to, created by concatenating the location’s pathname, search, and hash properties.
>
> to - An object that can have any of the following properties:

- pathname: A string representing the path to link to.
- search: A string representation of query parameters.
- hash: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
- state: State to persist to the location.

[react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

Answer (score 0):

Since `<Link />` is a component from a third-party library, it can have any props it wants and is not limited to the html element props in React's docs.

In this case `to` is the name of the prop used by React Router to specify where the Link component should "link to" when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

A `to` prop is typically used for linking to other documents, such as a CSS stylesheet.

Whereas the `href` prop is used to link to an external page, such as `<Link href="https://www.youtube.com"></Link>` would take the user to YouTube.